# converting Neoload script to Jmeter script

Tags: java, jmeter, neoload

Is there a possibility of converting the Neoload script to the Jmeter script?
If yes, then how?

I have solutions for other performance testing tools to Jmeter, but not for Neoload to Jmeter.

Comment: This pattern usually indicates that you are not receiving value from your current tool.   Your current tool is very capable, and you are moving to a tool that is less capable requiring additional tools to meet the same level of feature and functionality.   If you do not solve why you are not achieving at least a very high return on your performance testing tool investment (200%++) then the same problem of value generation will follow to the new tool.

Comment: Hi @JamesPulley,
The question was asked just for a blocker solution, Not for any marketing advice :)

Comment: Just bringing up a pattern from three decades worth of consulting services delivery.  When you switch tools, if you do not figure out why you are not receiving value from a high feature/high capability tool to a tool with less capability, then the pattern that impacted delivery of value will follow to the new tool.

It's free advice.  Worth precisely what you paid for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) as a proxy for the Neoload.

Given you:

- Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
- [Configure Neoload to use JMeter as a proxy](https://documentation.tricentis.com/neoload/9.0/en/WebHelp/#683.htm#o24279)

when you replay your test scenario in Neoload JMeter will capture the requests and generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Managers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

You will need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) manually however. If your Neoload script has a lot of dynamic values you might want to use [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690665233-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) instead of JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, it has possibility to export recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters.

Comment: Ahh ok, It was my bad, I didn't look at it the other way around. But it helped, Thanks.